# Let [magic-2015] duel [magic-duels]

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [magic-duels](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels) is about the same game as [magic-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-2015), at least their description .

There's only 2 questions tagged [magic-duels](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels). Just wanted to be sure it is indeed the same game the 2 tags are talking about. The tags are almost identical.

Comment: They are not the same game. [magic-2015] refers to Duels of the Planeswalkers 2015, which is last year's game. [magic-duels] refers to Magic: Duels, which came out in July.

Comment: The description of magic-duels should be changed then, it's `Magic 2015 – Duels of the Planeswalkers is a video game based on the collectible card game of the same name, first published by Wizards of the Coast in 1993.`

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on it

Comment: OK, the [magic-duels] tag now has a different description than the [magic-2015] tag.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Unrelated side note - I don't know if you knew but you can use tag formatting in comments. `[tag:magic-2015]` will give [tag:magic-2015] for example

Comment: @murgatroid99 Can you write that as an answer so this question can be marked as answered?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau don't self-answer by changing the entirety of the question.

Comment: @MrLemon didn't want to self-answer but the question changed since at first it looked like we could burninate a tag while they were not about the same game, so it became a question to clarify the [tag:magic-duels]  tag afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@murgatroid99 has clarified that the tags do not refer to the same game:

> They are not the same game. [magic-2015] refers to Duels of the Planeswalkers 2015, which is last year's game. [magic-duels] refers to Magic: Duels, which came out in July.

The tag wiki excerpt was changed to reflect this.